# Bash shell file size comparison inside nested for loop

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, file-io, scripting

Say I want to compare sizes of several files in different folders at once.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in folder1/*.*; do
size1=$(stat -c%s "$i")

  for j in folder2/*.*; do
    size2=$(stat -c%s "$j")
    total=0;

    while [ "$size1" -ge $total ]; do
      (( total+=size2 ))
      $j >> text.txt
    done
  done  
done
cat text.txt
```

For each file from folder1 I'd like this script to write down names of first taken files of folder2 which `sum` is less than the size of a given file in folder1. When `total` gets more than `$i` it means that we have found enough files which total sum is bigger than `$i`.

Output in a simple row side by side.
file: `file2-1 file2-2 file2-3 ...`
Is it even possible to achieve by using only given means?

Comment: `total+=j` adds the string `"` to the variable `$total`. You probably meant the arithmetic expression `(( total += j ))` instead.

Comment: You have to unquote the patterns; your outer loop, for example, has exactly one iteration, with `i` set to the literal string `folder1/*.*`.

Comment: Use shellcheck.net on your code.

Comment: @choroba thanks for your clarification! you got it right, I've made some changes

Comment: @chepner thank you! that was useful!